# Set a key if it does not exist, otherwise return its value

Tags: redis

I don't seem to find a command in Redis to achieve the following:

*Set a key if it does not exist, otherwise return its value*

Is there any way of achieving this in one transaction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One transaction? sure. One command? Don't think so.

Within a transaction, use SETNX to set a key if it does not exist, then get the value.

```
MULTI
SETNX keyName value
GET keyName
EXEC
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. 
In your approach, how would I be able to set the EXPIRE on the keyName if it did not exist before?

Comment: If you are using redis 2.6 or later you can accomplish this with a set command: `SET keyName value NX EX timeout_seconds`. See https://redis.io/commands/set

Answer (score 5):

(disclaimer: I'm a Lua kind of guy, the accepted answer is perfectly valid) One server-side Lua script? sure. One command? Don't think so ;)

Here's one way of doing it with [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/eval):

```
local v = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
if v then
  return v
end
return redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
```

Comment: In terms of speed, do you think the Lua approach would outperform the MULTI approach?

Comment: They should be about the same, but you can easily benchmark that.